# Can not insert data into database prepared statemend using looping for

Tags: java, mysql

Hy, i want to insert data into database using prepareStatement method, and it works normally, but when i insert data from loop for, data won't insert to db.
Here's my code:

```
PreparedStatement stmts = connection.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO detil_bet (id_user, id_room, id_game, bettype, total, win, lose) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )"
);
stmts.setInt(1, Uid);
stmts.setInt(2, idRoom);
stmts.setInt(3, idg);
int count = 0;
int size = 10;
String betsmall=""+0;
String betbig = ""+1;
String Z = "";
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    String[] b = {betsmall,betbig};
    count++;
    if(!b[i].equals(""+0)) {
        if(count > 0) {
             Z += "; ";
        }
        Z += "S" + count + ":" + b[i];
        stmts.setString(4, Z);
    }
}
stmts.setInt(5, tobet);
      if(pay >= tobet){
      stmts.setInt(6, pay - tobet);
      }else if (pay <= tobet){
          stmts.setInt(6, 0);
      }
      if(tobet >= pay){
          stmts.setInt(7, tot + (tot*-2));
      }
      else if (tobet <= pay){
          stmts.setInt(7, 0);
      }
      stmts.executeUpdate();

    }
```

index 1,2 and 3 works fine, the problem is index number 4, it doesn't work

Comment: You have 7 parameters not just 4.  Why would you loop around 10 times re-setting the value of parameter 4?

Comment: yes i have 7 parameters, but params 5-7 its okay.

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: and i changed size into 7 , still same

Comment: Bobby, in this code `stmts.setString(4, Z);` you are only ever setting parameter number 4

Comment: because there's no error berfore i change parameter number 4 into loop for

Comment: is there ultimately an executeQuery or what

Comment: Boddy what is the error?

Comment: now i already input full code, sorry before

Comment: It hits the [Query Log](http://i.imgur.com/LYJY85r.jpg) no?

Comment: OK making more sense.  But maybe make your `Z` string and then `setString(4, Z)` after the loop

Comment: so.Docs Query Log link: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/5102/log-files/18052/general-query-log#t=201609080208119585709

Comment: So if you have the General Query Log turned on (for debugging purposes) .... every query gets logged if it hits the server

Comment: Naturally turn off the GQL when all is well as it slows down performance and bloats up your filesystem

Comment: And while I am at it, doing a critique on answers, Bobby, you have 21 questions, only 2 accepted answers (green check marks), a lot of decent answers from others to you, and pretty much no comments from you to people that took the time to answer for you

Comment: That is not the way we roll here.